# jQuery UI / How to allow a sortable to receive but no to send items?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a few jQuery UI sortable lists and would like to move the items from one list to another. Except one blocked list: this should be able to receive items from other lists but the items inside this list shouldn't even react to attempts to be moved. Is this possible? How? I tried to use .sortable("cancel") in the start event but this seems not to work...

Please see here, the second list should be the "blocked" one: http://jsfiddle.net/r1rffht7/

```
 $(function() {
   $( ".sortable_list" ).sortable({
     connectWith: ".connectedSortable",             
   }).disableSelection();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your JQuery-UI `sortable` function by using the `cancel` selector like so (or see this **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1rffht7/1/)**:

**Note:** make sure to include your `sortable_list` class in the `blocked_list` div.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sortable_list").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    cancel: ".blockedList"
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.blockedList {
  border: 1px solid #f00 !important;
}

.sortable_list,
.blockedList {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sortable_list li,
.sortable_list .li,
.blockedList li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h3>Conected lists : You can move items between any list</h3>
<ul id="sortable1" class="sortable_list connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">List 1 - Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">List 1 - Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">List 1 - Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">List 1 - Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">List 1 - Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="sortable_list blockedList connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">List 2 - Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">List 2 - Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">List 2 - Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">List 2 - Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">List 2 - Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable3" class="sortable_list connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">List 3 - Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">List 3 - Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">List 3 - Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">List 3 - Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">List 3 - Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable4" class="sortable_list connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">List 4 - Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">List 4 - Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">List 4 - Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">List 4 - Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">List 4 - Item 5</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need! Don't know how I didn't see this option before... :-)

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it helped.